# How to check if an Object is a Userform?

Tags: vba, userform

I'm working on code that can listen for all events that take place in a UserForm including the UserForm itself.

The main method takes in **either an** `MSForms.Control` **or** `MSForms.UserForm` as it's the main parameter. To accommodate for either option the parameter is passed in as an Object (see below).

```vb
Public Sub AddEventListner(ByRef ControlOrForm As Object)
  'Do next steps for adding listeners...
End Sub
```

How can I check to see if a Userform was the object that was passed in?

The solution I came up with is to loop each Userform in `VBA.UserForms` and check if the name matches the Object that was passed in. This currently works for my needs; however, I want to see if there is a **more reliable solution** than depending on the name matching?

```vb
'CHECK TO SEE IF OBJ IS A USERFORM
Private Function IsUserform(ByRef Obj As Object) As Boolean

    Dim Form As Object
    For Each Form In VBA.UserForms

      'IF NAME MATCHES THEN IT MUST BE A USERFORM
      On Error GoTo NotUserform
      If Form.Name = Obj.Name Then
        IsUserform = True
        Exit Function
      End If

    Next

NotUserform:

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested, but maybe something like this:

```
Private Function IsUserform(ByRef Obj As Object) As Boolean

      If TypeOf Obj Is MSForms.UserForm Then
        IsUserform = True
      Else 
        IsUserform = False
      End If

End Function
```

It avoids a loop at least.

**Edit:** In the interest of a terser syntax the function below takes @ADJ 's suggestion into account.

```
Private Function IsUserform(ByRef Obj As Object) As Boolean

      IsUserform = TypeOf Obj Is MSForms.UserForm

End Function
```

Comment: Tested it and it works perfectly. I tried to use `TypeOf Obj` before but couldn't figure out how to get it to work. I was missing the `is` from my if statement. Thank you!

Comment: `IsUserForm = (TypeOf Obj is MSForms.UserForm)`. No need for all the extra lines. And yes, my `(`,`)` are not necessary either.

Comment: @AJD Indeed. The one liner is always looks the cleanest. Mad at my for not writing that originally.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble seems to be that an MsForms.Frame is also an MsForms.UserForm. So the result is not really reliable. The solution I use therefore instead is:

```
Private Function IsForm(ByVal if_object As Object) As Boolean
    Dim o As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set o = if_object.Parent
    IsForm = Err.Number <> 0
End Function
```

Not as elegant but it works. An MsForms.Frame object returns False and an MsForms.UserForm object returns True.

Answer (score 1):

To deduce whether the object is an existing user form (VBA window).

Make sure it is:

1. Not Nothing.
2. Of type MSForms.UserForm.
3. Not of type MSForms.Control, since objects of type MSForms.MultiPage and MSForms.Frame also passes as type MSForms.UserForm.

   ```
    Private Function IsUserForm(ByRef oObject As Object) As Boolean

        If oObject Is Nothing Then
            Let IsUserForm = False
        Else
            Let IsUserForm = TypeOf oObject Is MSForms.UserForm And Not TypeOf oObject Is MSForms.Control
        End If

    End Function
   ```

Comment: Both this and Walter's answer below work whereas rickmanalexander's above also returns true for Multipages and Frames as mentioned in point 3.